# impoly crash error in Matlab

Tags: matlab, crash-reports

I've recently been developing a GUI, which worked fine until Matlab crashed while running an unrelated code. A section of my code which allows a user to draw a ROI no longer works and reports an error with my impoly call (worked perfectly before Matlab crashed):

```
function cb(src,evt)
handles = guidata(src);  %# import the data from the object
images=handles.images;
start = handles.view_slice;
last = handles.slices;
imshow(images(:,:,start),[])
h=impoly;
position = getPosition(h);
```

The error I now get is:

```
Error using hittest
Invalid object handle
Error in imshared.ipthittest (line 33)
h = hittest(hFigure, currentPoint);
Error in findLowestManagedObject (line 14)
    hit_obj =
    imshared.ipthittest(hFigure,buttonMotionEvent.currentPoint);
Error in iptPointerManager>createPointerManager/updatePointer
(line 334)
        overMe =
        findLowestManagedObject(hFigure,mouseMotionEvent);
Error in
iptPointerManager>createPointerManager/enablePointerManager (line
259)
            updatePointer(figHandle, evt);
Error in iptPointerManager (line 72)
    pointerManager.API.enable();
Error in manageInteractivePlacement (line 76)
      iptPointerManager(h_fig,'Enable');
Error in impoly>impolyAPI (line 245)
      placement_aborted =
      manageInteractivePlacement(h_axes,h_group,@placePolygon,@buttonUpPlacement);
Error in impoly (line 97)
            [h_group,draw_api] = impolyAPI(varargin{:});
Error in volume_scan>cb (line 288)
h=impoly;
Error while evaluating uitoggletool OnCallback
```

Apart from this not working, there is other weirdness including text stuck in a table on GUIDE (which I cannot remove) and a checkbox text which keeps defaulting to the 3rd option

Anybody got any ideas? Is there a crash file somewhere that needs to be reset/removed? I'm using 2012b.

Thanks, Jim

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? Other than this I can only think of these questions: Is the source really the same, did the other code change any files or settings, change the path or overload functions?

Comment: Just to add to this, I've rebooted, and even re-installed Matlab and theres still no solution. Funnily enough, a call to impoly elsewhere in the code works perfectly fine. Other people online have had this error too and simply had to re-write the script, which I'll try next.